# Why dart optional named argument is not null if not provided?

Tags: dart, optional-parameters, named

When optional named parameter is not provided, why it is not `null` *as expected*?

```
void main() {
  num double({v: num}) {
    if (v == null)
      return 0;
    else
      return v * 2;
  }

  print(double(v: 2));
  print(double());
  print('done');
}
```

which output as

```
4
Uncaught TypeError: v.$mul is not a function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
num double({v: num}) {
```

defines a named parameter `v` of type `dynamic` with the default value `num` (a type)

It should instead be

```
num double({num v}) {
```

to make your code work as expected